# Cannot get cURL to post to URL

Tags: php, post, curl

I have been trying to get a post request to work via cURL. I am a complete novice at cURL so I think it is a simple mistake. I have sent the data through a HTML form and through Linux terminal and it woks fine. Not sure why I it doesn't work in cURL though.

```
<?php
$PaymentUrl = "https://test@test.com";
$PostString = "value1=value&value1=value&value1=value
value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&        
value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&value1=value&    
value1=value&value1=value";
$ch = curl_init($PaymentUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,17);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Please note I changed the values and URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the output you get when you print $result variable?

Comment: as far as I can see your data is being sent in QueryString which is possible with GET method , can you change it accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure but try to add these options `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST` => true (or 1), not the number of fields, perhaps that's the problem here. Of course, if it doesn't work, inspect `curl_error($ch);`....

Comment: @Satya: the string is the normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` kind used in most posts. It does look like a GET query indeed, but it's just as valid as a POST body.

Comment: I changed CURLOPT_POST to 1. There is no response what-so-ever or output? Yes it is suppose to be a post.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```